# string.sub и русский текст в lua

Tags: lua, love2d

Хотел сделать что-то вроде эффекта набора в LÖVE. Написал вот такой код:

```
text    = "I'M HACKER!!!"
toPrint = ""
timerMax = 0.1
timer    = 0.1
pos      = 0

function love.draw(dt)
    love.graphics.setColor(0, 255, 0)
    love.graphics.print(toPrint, 10, 10)
end        

function love.update(dt)
    timer = timer - dt
    if timer <= 0 then
        timer   = 0.1
        pos     = pos + 1
        toPrint = string.sub(text, 0, pos)
    end
end
```

Всё работает. Записал в text русские символы:

```
text    = "ЙА ХАКИР!!!"
toPrint = ""
timerMax = 0.1
timer    = 0.1
pos      = 0

function love.draw(dt)
    love.graphics.setColor(0, 255, 0)
    love.graphics.print(toPrint, 10, 10)
end        

function love.update(dt)
    timer = timer - dt
    if timer <= 0 then
        timer   = 0.1
        pos     = pos + 1
        toPrint = string.sub(text, 0, pos)
    end
end
```

И теперь LÖVE выдает ошибку:

```
Error: main.lua:9: UTF-8 decoding error: Not enough space
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'print'
    main.lua:9: in function 'draw'
    [string "boot.lua"]:468: in function <[string "boot.lua"]:436>
    [C]: in function 'xpcall'
```

Могу ли я как-то починить это?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
--[[
Скачайте либу отсюда:
raw.githubusercontent.com/markandgo/love2d-libs/master/lib/global/utf8.lua
и переименуйте её в "utf8lib", поскольку в lua уже есть библиотека с таким именем.
]]

require "utf8lib"

local text     = "I AM ФACKER!!!"
local toPrint  = ""
local timerMax = 0.1
local timer    = 0.1
local pos      = 0

function love.load()
    -- Подключите какой-нибудь русский шрифт
    -- например отсюда http://www.dafont.com/press-start-2p.font
    love.graphics.setNewFont("press-start-2p.ttf", 32)
end

function love.draw(dt)
    love.graphics.setColor(0, 255, 0)
    love.graphics.print(toPrint, 10, 10)
end

function love.update(dt)
    timer = timer - dt
    if timer <= 0 then
        timer = 0.1
        pos = pos + 1
        -- используйте string.utf8sub вместо string.sub
        toPrint = string.utf8sub(text, 0, pos)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Не нужно ничего скачивать. В *love2d* уже встроена библиотека `utf8`, правда там не реализована функция `sub`. А еще в стандартном шрифте *love2d* нет русских символов, так что будут квадратики. Можно исправить, поставив другой шрифт:

```
utf8=require("utf8")
-- Нет функции utf8.sub, реализуем ее сами
function utf8.sub(str,x,y)
  local x2,y2
  x2=utf8.offset(str,x)
  if y then
    y2=utf8.offset(str,y+1)
    if y2 then
      y2=y2-1
    end
  end
  print(x,y,"|",x2,y2)
  return string.sub(str,x2,y2)
end

text    = "ЙА ХАКИР!!!"
toPrint = ""
-- timerMax = 0.1 -- Не используется
timer    = 0.1
pos      = 0
print(text)
function love.draw(dt)
    love.graphics.setColor(0, 255, 0)
    love.graphics.print(toPrint, 10, 10)
end        

function love.update(dt)
    timer = timer - dt
    if timer <= 0 then
        timer   = 0.1
        pos     = pos + 1
        toPrint = utf8.sub(text, 0, pos)
    end
end
```